# Can I partially specialize a template with a pattern like foo<T..., int, U...>?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

If this is possible, one can index into a variadic template parameter pack without recursion. However, GCC is [refusing to pick up my partial specialization](http://ideone.com/pZh4f) here:

```
template <int I, typename List>
struct element_impl;

template <typename... TL, int... IL, typename T, int I, typename... TR, int... IR>
struct element_impl<I, typelist<pair<TL,IL>..., pair<T,I>, pair<TR,IR>...>> {
    typedef T type;
};
```

> prog.cpp: In instantiation of '`element<0, typelist<int, double, char,
>   float, long int> >`':
>   prog.cpp:52:34:   instantiated from here
>   prog.cpp:47:79: error: invalid use of incomplete type '`struct element_impl<0, typelist<pair<int, 0>, pair<double, 1>, pair<char, 2>, pair<float, 3>, pair<long int, 4> >`'

Is GCC buggy, or am I ignoring some limitation of variadic templates?

Comment: With [this simple code](http://ideone.com/CrNSc), GCC says : `error: parameter pack 'T' must be at the end of the template parameter list`. So I tend to think that it is a language limitation.

Comment: @Nawaz That's not at all the same.

Comment: It is not "exactly" same, but the error message is pretty much clear: the parameter pack *must be* at the end of the template parameter list. GCC repeats the same message here as well : http://ideone.com/2Rifn

Comment: @Nawaz seems you're right. :(

Comment: @Nawaz you got a primary template there. That restriction does not apply to partial specializations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec says at 14.8.2.5p9

> If P has a form that contains `<T>` or `<i>`, then each argument `Pi` of the respective template argument list `P` is compared with the corresponding argument `Ai` of the corresponding template argument list of `A`. If the template argument list of `P` contains a pack expansion that is not the last template argument, the entire template argument list is a non-deduced context.

Your `typelist<T>` unfortunately matches that pattern.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the Standard's text in simple words, possibly with one or two examples?

Comment: @Nawaz @RMartinho showed an excellent example of this rule, possibly better than anything I could come up with. `<T>` means "template argument list containing a type parameter (pack)" and "<i>" means "template argument list containing a non-type parameter (pack)".

Answer (score 2):

AFAICT, the rules for matching partial specializations are the same as the rules type deduction of function parameters. And §14.8.2.1/1 says the following:

> For a function parameter pack that occurs at the end of the
>   *parameter-declaration-list*, the type `A` of each remaining argument of
>   the call is compared with the type `P` of the *declarator-id* of the
>   function parameter pack. Each comparison deduces template arguments
>   for subsequent positions in the template parameter packs expanded by
>   the function parameter pack. For a function parameter pack that does
>   not occur at the end of the *parameter-declaration-list*, the type of
>   the parameter pack is a non-deduced context.

So the packs `TL` and `IL` cannot be deduced in this case, and the partial specialization is not picked.