# Variadic template with type at end

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to write a variadic function that will specialize on the last argument provided.

```
    // we take em all as long as they are convertible to string
    template<typename... Args>
    void warn(Args... args, string s){
        vector<string> joinable{args..., s};
        SMDiagnostic w(TUName, SourceMgr::DK_Warning,
                util::join(joinable));
        w.print("CGD.so", errs());
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void warn(Args... args, Value const * v){
        string buffer;
        raw_string_ostream os(buffer);
        v->print(os);
        warn(args..., os.str());
    }

    template<typename... Args>
    void warn(Args... args, CallInst const * ci){
        warn(args..., dyn_cast<Value>(ci));
    }
```

And i try to call them with

```
warn(me, someCallInst);
```

But clang gives me a weird errord

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'warn'
       warn("We found a function usage that is not a call!! Ignoring\n", inst);
       ^~~~
../llvm_opt_pass/cgd.cpp:1062:8: note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
                void warn(Args... args, CallInst const * ci){
                     ^
../llvm_opt_pass/cgd.cpp:1054:8: note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
                void warn(Args... args, Value const * v){
                     ^
../llvm_opt_pass/cgd.cpp:1046:8: note: candidate function not viable: requires 1 argument, but 2 were provided
                void warn(Args... args, string s){
```

What do i have to do to be able to use the variadic template like that?

Comment: @BoPersson: This looks different to me, it seems to be about overloading of functions and how to overload on the *last* parameter of a variadic prefix.

Comment: In short: The types are not deduced unless the pack is at the end of the parameter list. `void warn(string s, Args... args)` works, but `void warn(Args... args, string s)` doesn't.

Comment: @BoPersson That is the answer. Maybe you should make that the answer and link to the other post. The other example is too convoluted.

Comment: @RedX - I didn't really want to write an answer because it would look *exactly* like [Johannes' answer to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11073815/597607).